# How to get selected and unselected pending changes in TFS outside of a check-in policy?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there a way to get selected and unselected pending changes in TFS outside of a check-in policy?

I'm aware of the `IPendingCheckinPendingChanges` and `IPendingCheckin` interfaces, but is there a way to retrieve instances of those without being in a check-in policy or Visual Studio add-on?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that via [SavedCheckin.IsExcluded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.savedcheckin.isexcluded.aspx) method. Please check the following code which is quoted from Kelley's second reply in this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e97785f4-3595-4ebe-a1f1-db8a9381bc12/change-list-of-files-to-exclude-in-pending-changes).

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        Workspace workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace("$/sourcelocation");

        IEnumerable<PendingChange> pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChangesEnumerable();
        SavedCheckin savedCheckin = workspace.LastSavedCheckin;
        List<PendingChange> excludedChanges = new List<PendingChange>();

        foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
        {
            if (savedCheckin.IsExcluded(change.ServerItem))
            {
                excludedChanges.Add(change);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising-- I will investigate when I have time and let you know if I have issues.

Comment: The docs mention that this is either the most recently unshelved shelveset or the last failed check-in. Does Visual Studio update this more frequently than those occasions (i.e., with every file checked out or reverted)?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, could you please share here the article you're checking so that I can better understand your concerns.

Comment: Absolutely. Here it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.lastsavedcheckin.aspx

Comment: I tried it out today and it's *very* close- it works when I'm not working on code in Visual Studio and the app is closed. But if Visual Studio is open and I'm making changes, the LastSavedCheckin isn't always in sync with what Visual Studio displays. If there was a way to force Visual Studio to keep the LastSavedCheckin synched with its own view of the workspace, this could work for sure.